# I want to convert string to date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, zone

```
var date = new Date().toTimeString()
console.log(date)
```

The above code output is this String : 21:27:52 GMT+0430 (India Daylight Time)

how to convert this string to Date or Number

Comment: You cant convert this string to Date because in the string there's no date at all, only time

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov i did not understand

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek thanks . do you have any idea ?

Comment: What you have is a **time**. A JavaScript Date object represents both a time of day and a specific day of a specific year.

Comment: @Pointy thanks my friend

Answer (score 0):

You are printing time by using the `toTimeString()` method.
I believe you are looking for `new Date().toLocaleDateString()` for the date string. The output is `3/24/2020`

If you want to play around more, feel free to explore the Conversion Getter section of this documentation page.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date